# Oreo DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) returns path instead of Long

Tags: android, file, path, filesystems, android-8.1-oreo

I'm trying to get the real path of a file stored in the Android file system (I'm testing on an Emulator with `Android 8.1`)

here is my code:

```
final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
```

For earlier versions of `Android 8.0`, the variable `id` contains a `long` value so the next line works as expected.

On `Android 8` the variable `id` contains a path like this `raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_file.pdf`, so the casting `Long.valueOf(id))` throws a `'java.lang.NumberFormatException' Exception.`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try adding this line before converting to long : `str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");` that way it won't be any confusion in case your String contains letters or symbols.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. If you have something like `raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_file.pdf` then the path is `/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_file.pdf`. What are you after?

Comment: it makes sense to me. Before `Android 8`, the variable `id` contains a `Long` value so i can prepare the `contentUri` with a valid path. From `Android 8`, the variable `id` contains an invalid path which is not found in the `Android` file system.

Answer (score 32):

Had the same problem solved it by doing the following.

```
final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
            }
            try {
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 return null;
            }
      }
```

Solution was found in a comment https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/issues/318

Comment: Unable to get path for images only working for video, I am getting Request "header queries do not support projections, selections or sorting" while getting "cursor"
I am using Android 9

Comment: This code catches the exception, but there is no meaningful action afterwards. How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Unstable unfortunately, creating a temp file via reading the stream looks more applicable, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154391/4629420

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
 id = id.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```