# API level 29 Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT returning wrong id from downloads folder

Tags: android

I am trying to find the full file path for an URI returned from file picker intent. I have downloaded an image from internet which was saved in the browser default download folder. The problem is the id returned by DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(content_describer) is like "msf:254" instead of Long type id generally returned. The code is as following

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri content_describer = data.getData();
        String src = content_describer.getPath();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        Log.e("selected file", content_describer.toString());
        String filename = content_describer.getLastPathSegment();
        Log.e("selected path", filename);
        Log.e("authority",content_describer.getAuthority());


        if (content_describer.getAuthority().equals("com.android.externalstorage.documents")) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(content_describer);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            Log.e("npath", "getPath() docId: " + docId + ", split: " + split.length + ", type: " + type);
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                if (split.length > 1) {
                    Log.e("nnpath1", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1]);
                    curFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                } else {
                    Log.e("nnpath2", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
                }
                // This is for checking SD Card
            } else {
                Log.e("nnpath3", "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/"));
                curFile = "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
            }
        }

        if (content_describer.getAuthority().equals("com.android.providers.downloads.documents")) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(content_describer);
            Log.e("docid",docId);

            Uri ci = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(docId));

            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };
            Cursor cursor10 = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ci, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            if (cursor10 != null && cursor10.moveToFirst()) {


                final int column_index = cursor10.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                Log.e("imgpp", cursor10.getString(column_index));
                Log.e("imgpp2", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
                File fn = new File(cursor10.getString(column_index));
                Log.e("imgpp3", fn.getPath());
                curFile = fn.getPath();
            }
        }

        if (content_describer.getAuthority().equals("com.android.providers.media.documents")) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(content_describer);
            Log.e("docid", docId);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };
            Cursor cursor1 = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.moveToFirst()) {


                final int column_index = cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                Log.e("imgpp", cursor1.getString(column_index));
                Log.e("imgpp2", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
                File fn = new File(cursor1.getString(column_index));
                Log.e("imgpp3", fn.getPath());
                curFile = fn.getPath();
            }
        }

        Log.e("final path",curFile);


    }
}
```

Please note if I pick the same image going via Image->Downwnload, the above code works normally but when same file is picked from Downloads folder, following error is thrown

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.flexi.app.android, PID: 15414
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196709, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:253 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.flexi.app.android/com.flexi.app.android.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/253
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4830)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4871)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/253
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:934)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:872)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:830)
    at com.flexi.app.android.fragments.ProfileImageFragment.onActivityResult(ProfileImageFragment.java:171)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
    at com.flexi.app.android.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8091)
```

The URI is reported as content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A253
Any idea what is msf? I have seen image, video, audo but noticed msf for first time.

Comment: `The problem is the id returned by DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(content_describer) is like "msf:254" instead of Long type id generally returned.` Long?  That function always returns a String. And especially on some devices the Download directory behaves different from the primary or SD card partion. For a separate Down;load partion "msd:254" is ok. Query the contentresolver for the DISPLAY_NAME.

Comment: Anyhow you are trying to obtain a classic file path from that content scheme. You should not even try to do such. For what do you need a file path? If you wanna read the file you can read from the content scheme directly.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/253` That is indeed an impossible content scheme. You mistreated the original obtained schem what probably will have looked like `conten://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/253`.

Comment: `Uri ci = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(docId)); Remove that line and do not query(ci, but the original uri.
`

Comment: `I am trying to find the full file path for an URI returned from file picker intent.` ?? I think you are trying to find a classic file path from the obtained uri. Why ? For what do you need that file path? You can do all with the content scheme. Dont spend further time on this awfull code and learn to use the content scheme directly. Soon you have Android Q and then you should use Storage Access Framework.

Comment: @blackapps I need to upload the file to a webservice. I am using Ion and it required File type to add file attachment... What alternate will you suggest in this situation? I need to convert Uri to File...

Comment: You can make a copy to a file path and use that copy.

Comment: any example on how to make copy?

Comment: You read in chunks from the inputstream obtained by getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()) and white them to a FileOutputStream. You can find code everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Of you add this as answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @blackapps Add answer so others will get help

Answer (score 3):

When you get "msf:xxx" in URI, use below solution:

```
if (id != null && id.startsWith("msf:")) {
                    final File file = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), Constant.TEMP_FILE + Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getContentResolver().getType(imageUri)).split("/")[1]);
                    try (final InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri); OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                        int read;

                        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }

                        output.flush();
                        return file;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

I have fixed this issue and it's working 100% for msf. :)

Also Delete the temp file after the completion of your work:

```
private void deleteTempFile() {
        final File[] files = requireContext().getCacheDir().listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (final File file : files) {
                if (file.getName().contains(Constant.TEMP_FILE)) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here TEMP_FILE value is "temp."

Answer (score 0):

I found the way from comment section. Thanks to @blackapps.

```
 val inputStream = context!!.contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
 val docFile =File("${activity!!.cacheDir}/doc_${sharedPreferences.getString("applno", "")}.pdf")
 if (!docFile.exists()) {
        docFile.createNewFile()
 }
```

copyStreamToFile(inputStream!!,docFile)

```
private fun copyStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputFile: File) {
    inputStream.use { input ->
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        outputStream.use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // buffer size
            while (true) {
                val byteCount = input.read(buffer)
                if (byteCount < 0) break
                output.write(buffer, 0, byteCount)
            }
            output.flush()
        }
    }
}
```