# I am using the same code in two diffrent applications one is thrwoing numberexception why?

Tags: java, android, image-compression

I am bulding an application where user need to upload the multiple images and i am using sillicompressor library code to compress those images before uploading them to firebase storage. I have the two application with that same code completely both of them were working fine but now the one is crashing the time user selects the multiple images. Please guide me

**CODE WHICH IS CREATING PROBLEM**

```
  //this part is to select multiple images
                for (int i = 0; i < countofImages; i++) {

                    if (imageList.size() < 8)
                    {
                         imageuri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                        File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));
                        compresseduri = Uri.fromFile(file);


                        imageList.add(new CustomModel(getfilename(imageuri), compresseduri));
                    } else
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't select more than 8 images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}
```

**ERROR IS THROWING ON THIS LINE**

```
File file = new File(SiliCompressor.with(getContext()).compress(FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), imageuri), new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "temp" + i)));
```

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:126968"
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:808)
at com.iceteck.silicompressorr.FileUtils.getPath(FileUtils.java:288)
at com.shrihari.backsoon.Listing_Fragment_3$5.onActivityResult(Listing_Fragment_3.java:263)
```

Comment: are your 2 programs using the same input data? the problem is with the input `msf:126968` is clearly not a number

Comment: @Pavel The number parse action is not done by him intentionally. Checking the library GitHub it shows that `FileUtils.java:288` is calling `Long.valueOf(id)` which id is `final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);`

Comment: The error is thrown from the 1st arg of `compress(String, File)`. And 1st arg is origin from the library `FileUtils.getPath(Context, Uri)`.  REF GIT: https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/blob/9cc0c541627ff1ad61083bf86d3d992369751e3a/silicompressor/src/main/java/com/iceteck/silicompressorr/FileUtils.java

Comment: So maybe someone can help to take a look of the GIT library file there. Also OP may provide an `imageUri` param example which will lead to such exception.

Comment: Although I am not familiar with `DocumentProvider`, searching it on Google give some hints how to "correct" the id value. But this will require you to modify the library source code on your own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660420/api-level-29-intent-action-get-content-returning-wrong-id-from-downloads-folder/62154391#62154391

Comment: @Pavel sorry i m not getting what u mean

Comment: brother the confusion is that the same code is working on the another application and was working with this also but all of a sudden this exception occured

Comment: hey can u please help me with this i still stucked at this